# Subspace problem

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Can somebody tell me if my solution on the following problem is right?

> Show that set is a vector subspace 
>   $$ L:\mathbb{R}^{3\times3}\to\mathbb{R}^{3\times3}$$
>   $$\{A \in \mathbb{R}^{3\times3} \mid L(A)=0 \}$$
>   $$A \to L(A):=A +A^T $$

Solution

> 1. Let $A$ be the zero matrix, then
>      $$L(0)=0.$$
> 2. Let $A$ and $B$ be two 3x3 matrices, then 
>      $$L(A + B) = L(A) + L(B) = 0+0=0.$$
> 3. Let $c$ be a scalar in $\mathbb{R}$, then
>      $$L(cA)= c\cdot L(A) = c\cdot0 =0.$$

So the set is a subspace? However I am not sure if it's meant to be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{3\times3}$ as in the problem is only that mentioned.

I am asked also to give the basis of $L$ and the dimension but there is not a given matrix only this set here, does someone know I can do that? Or just the Problem is not somehow false written or so?

Comment: You haven't told us what $L$ is.  Is it meant to just be a linear map from $\mathbb R^9$ to...something?

Comment: So $L(A) = 0$ and $L(A) = A + A^T$ at the same time ? Please decide which one

Comment: Not really sure I have this problem from a book and I dont have a solution .

Comment: Let $S = \left\{ A\color{blue}{\in \mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}} \mid L(A) = 0\right\}$. Then you're right, $S$ is a subspace of $\color{blue}{\mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}}$. For your proofs, you should let $A$ and $B$ be matrices *from that set $S$* (and say so).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your set is the kernel of the linear map $L$. The fact that $L(A)=A+A^T$ is irrelevant here. The kernel of *any* linear map is always a vector subspace (for the reason that you mentioned).

On the other hand, in order to determine a basis of $\ker L$, you need to know which map $L$ is. Since$$\ker L=\{A\,|\,A=-A^T\},$$a basis of $\ker L$ is$$\left\{\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\-1&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&0&1\\0&0&0\\-1&0&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&-1&0\end{bmatrix}\right\},$$for instance.

Comment: and about my second question how can give the bais of L, when  I dont have a given matrix ? Or the basis of L can be everything as that is the kernel ?

Comment: I've edited my answer.